# Change the default destination folder for Make Table queries in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I inherited an Access db having many saved *Make Table queries* (MTQ). The problem is that they create the destination table in an external MDB, and the folder containing that external MDB may change depending on the environment.
All those saved MTQs have of course the destination db harcoded, with the full path:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM tablex IN tblNew INTO 'X:\myfolder\myexternal.mdb'
```

Is there a way to **modify the default destination folder** of Access so that I could later change those MTQ into:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM tablex IN tblNew INTO 'myexternal.mdb'
```

and have them automatically going to the appropriate folder ?
I tried using `ChDir` without success, and `CurrentProject.Path` is read only. Any other idea ?

Comment: @Remou: Thank you. I already have somthing like that. I just thought that the idea of changing the default folder could make things simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File->Options and change the default database folder. This works as you would wish.

In VBA:

```
SetOption "Default Database Directory", "Z:\Docs\"
```

This will then run, where test.accdb is in Docs:

```
SELECT *
FROM [;database=test.accdb].table1;
```

Note that an export will now also save in the new default folder, for example:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Query", "Query.txt"
```

Comment: Ideally: `Application.SetOption`

Comment: Why do you say that? Do you use Application.CurrentDb?

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that it "permanently" changes the Default folder.

Comment: Yes, there is no other possibility. Either "permanently" change the SQL or "permanently" change the folder.